# Uninitialised disk after erasing one partition on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, catalina, hdd

I have a 1 TB HDD and I had three partitions on it.

Two partitions had data on them and one was empty. However, when I was trying to move some files to the empty partition, it gave the error "file size too bit for partition type". Therefore I went to disk utility and erased the particular partition and gave the new format as MAC journaled. An error occurred as the partition was unmounted and now the entire disk is uninitialized.

It doesn't show the other two partitions as well. I ran first aid on the disk but the issue is still the same. The only other option disk utility shows are erasing the entire disk which I do not want to do because there is valuable data on the other two partitions.

[image: Disk status as of now.]

Earlier this showed three partitions and now I only see this. I somehow want to access the data on the other two partitions.

Comment: I would immediately try a data recovery tool like [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/).

Comment: In my opinion there is no need to hurry, just unmount and eject the disk. **Don't initialize or repair** it with Disk Utility or similar apps when asked. You probably killed the partition table (either MBR or GPT) but the partitions themselves are probably not affected.

Comment: I did unmount and ejected it. Mounted back in and the result is the same

Comment: Your goal is to recover the partition table (hence the partitions = volumes = data) and not the files themselves. Trying to recover the data itself will probably leave you with a bunch of randomly named files. This can be done manually (by inspecting the disk with a hexviewer and calculating the sizes of the vanished partitions/volumes) or with tools like testdisk or DiskDrill (a special mode of DiskDrill).

Comment: I can offer you to check the disk from remote. This requires you to install TeamViewer or a similar tool and allow access.

Comment: @klanomath thank you but I managed to fix it using testdisk tool on linux.